# Tomcat Server stopping when executing Vaadin webapp

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, vaadin

I developed a webapp with Vaadin and kept it running on an embedded Jetty Server. Now, in order to deploy it on the productive server, I need it to run on a Tomcat v7 server.
I took the WAR-file (built with Maven) and deployed it to Tomcat.
Now, when I call the Tomcat URL in the browser, the webapp starts and shows the Vaadin loading circle. After a few seconds, the circle disappears and Tomcat stops.

The Catalina Logfile says the following:

```
Nov 17, 2015 11:37:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5830 ms
Nov 17, 2015 11:37:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 17, 2015 11:37:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 17, 2015 11:37:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Nov 17, 2015 11:38:01 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/myWebapp] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create   memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
Nov 17, 2015 11:38:01 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/myWebapp] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.vaadin.util.CurrentInstance$1] (value [com.vaadin.util.CurrentInstance$1@d8b2a4cd]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{interface com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest=com.vaadin.util.CurrentInstance@d59e9a8b, class com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession=com.vaadin.util.CurrentInstance@bb1b7c4b, class com.vaadin.server.VaadinService=com.vaadin.util.CurrentInstance@5b5dec40, interface com.vaadin.server.VaadinResponse=com.vaadin.util.CurrentInstance@ea949e2b, class com.vaadin.ui.UI=com.vaadin.util.CurrentInstance@174bb6a7}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 17, 2015 11:38:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Which fault is likely to cause this behaviour? Do I need to perform certain steps in order to deploy a Jetty webapp on Tomcat?

Comment: Have a look at the other tomcat logs, probably there is something else logged

Comment: Besides what @AndréSchild said, check your application logs as well (if you have a dedicated logfile)